# Variables Comparison PHP

Tags: php, syntax, comparison

I'm really new at this so please be patient. I try to do a very basic operation: Compare two strings. It  seemed easy enough but I can't get it work. Here is a bit of code I made to check the value of $username before going further. But whatever value I give to $username it seems it never go through the if/else test since I never get any output on the screen. Why is that? Is it a syntax error, something else?

Thanks for help.

```
<?php
    $username = $_SESSION['Sess_User'];
    $password = $_SESSION['Sess_Code'];
    if (strcmp($username, "Admin") !== 0){
        echo "Acces Denied.";
    }else{ 
        echo "Ok, Go on.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please turn on error reporting and check your script again.

Comment: have you written session_start(); on top ?

Comment: echo $username and check

Comment: did you set session like this  : "session_start();"

Comment: becoz there is nothing wrong in your code in string comparision

Comment: The answers that suggest using `session_start();` are right about getting the correct data from `$_SESSION[]` but they don't explain why you don't get any output. I checked the posted code and got "Access Denied." (which is the correct output). Is this all the code?

Comment: seem @user2740749 not interested in answers :(

Answer (score 1):

**Just use simple these things :**

// For start a session

```
session_start();
```

// assign session value into variables

```
$username = $_SESSION['Sess_User'];
$password = $_SESSION['Sess_Code'];
```

// check comparision by using comparision operator

```
if ($username=="Admin"){
    echo "Acces Denied.";
}else{ 
    echo "Ok, Go on.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION['Sess_User'];
    $password = $_SESSION['Sess_Code'];
    if (strcmp($username, "Admin") !== 0){
        echo "Acces Denied.";
    }else{ 
        echo "Ok, Go on.";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `session_start();` at top of file

and `strcmp` is for case sensitive comparison you can use `strcasecmp` or directly comparison operator(==)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION['Sess_User'];
    $password = $_SESSION['Sess_Code'];

    //you can also use if($username == "Admin")
    if (strcasecmp($username, "Admin") !== 0){
        echo "Acces Denied.";
    }else{ 
        echo "Ok, Go on.";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['Sess_User'];
$password = $_SESSION['Sess_Code'];
if ($username=="Admin"){
  echo "Ok, Go on.";

}else{ 
    echo "Acces Denied.";
}
?>
```